# Is "the Vulture's soliloquy" real?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, stan-lee

[In Stan Lee's appearance](https://youtu.be/1vJpAXf5wyk) in the film *Mallrats*, he gives a character some dating advice and then reveals he made up the entire story.

> Oh, it was the Vulture's soliloquy, you know, from the Spider-Man anniversary issue "Love Be A Vulture Tonight".

Is this a real scene from a comic? Or was it made up for the film?

Comment: Google says no but none of the sources are "valid". Looks like it's all made up. If it were a real thing, the issue title would come up somewhere... which it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not real, and neither is the issue he names.

The first "anniversary" issue of Spider-Man, published in May 1988, was called "Venom". For the 50th anniversary we got an entire year of "anniversary issues" from March 2012 through March 2013, which were titled "I Killed Tomorrow", "Ends of the Earth", "No Turning Back", "Alpha", "Danger Zone", and "Dying Wish". The 75th anniversary issue, obviously, hasn't come out yet.

There was a special *100th Anniversary Edition* Marvel-Wide series; the *Spider-Man* issue of that series was part of the "Great Power" storyline.

None of these have a name even close to "Love Be A Vulture Tonight".